# Is $ x \log x = O(x^{1+\epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon > 0$?

Tags: inequality

I am an amateur.

**Claim**
$$ x \log x = O(x^{1+\epsilon}) \qquad (A) 
$$ 
for every $\epsilon > 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R} \;, x > 2$.

Tried to disproof this, but doubt the proof is correct.

Basic idea:  Define $f(x,\epsilon)= \frac{x \log x}{x^{1+\epsilon}}$,
show that $f(x,\epsilon)$ is unbounded.

I suppose if $a(x)/b(x,\epsilon)$ is unbounded it is impossible
$a(x)=O(b(x,\epsilon))$

Solving $x \log x = x^{1+\epsilon} $ gives 
$\epsilon_0 = -{\frac {\log  \left( x \right) -\log  \left( x\log  \left( x \right)  \right) }{\log  \left( x \right) }}$.

$\epsilon_0$ is positive for $x$ large enough.

Consider 
$$f(x,\epsilon / 10) = {\frac {{x}^{1/10}\log  \left( x \right) }{ \left( x\log  \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{1/10}}} \qquad (B) $$

(B) is unbounded and the limit at infinity is infinity for positive epsilon.

I suppose this shows (A) is false.

> Is this correct?  In particular "Basic idea" in case of typos.
>
> A correct proof or disproof of (A)?

Comment: What is the limit of $(\log x)/x^{\epsilon}$ when $x$ goes to 0 and $\epsilon$ is fixed?

Comment: @user37238 I don't know. Anyway I edited the question with $x > 2$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to know if, when $\alpha>0$,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^\alpha} = 0$$

It's true.

Let $x^\alpha=y$, or $x=y^{1/\alpha}$. Then the limit is the same as

$$\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{\log \left(y^{1/\alpha} \right)}{y} = \frac 1 \alpha\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{\log y }{y} $$

Now, you have only one case to check. Let $f(x)=\frac{\log{x}}{x}$, on $[1, +\infty[$, then

$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}$$

So $f' \leq 0$ and $f\geq 0$, thus $f$ has a limit when $x\to+\infty$.

If this limit is $A$, we already know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^\alpha}=\frac{A}{\alpha}$

Then

$$\frac{\log x}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}$$

The first factor tends to $0$ when $x\to+\infty$, and the second to $2A$.

Hence, for any $\alpha>0$,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log x}{x} =\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^\alpha}=0$$

And you can conclude that

$$\log x = o(x^{\alpha}) = O(x^{\alpha})$$

So

$$x \log x = o(x^{1+\alpha}) = O(x^{1+\alpha})$$

The little-o is slightly stronger here, but, it adds not much.

---

Note: you could of course have differentiated directly

$$\left(\frac{\log x}{x^\alpha}\right)' = \frac{1-\alpha \log x}{x^{\alpha+1}}$$

And you would finish the proof as easily.

Comment: Thank you. Will check this tomorrow. What is the first critical error in my proof?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ may be any positive value, but it must be fixed once and for all, not a function of $x$.

Comment: Fixed epsilon explains my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly more efficient to use [l'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^\alpha}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{\alpha n^{\alpha-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha n^\alpha}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you. Will check this tomorrow. What is the first critical error in my proof?

Comment: The assumption (A) does *not* imply that $x \log x = x^{1+\epsilon}$.